# Clean Architecture - Support plugins that can add new entities?

Tags: clean-architecture, plugin-architecture

I'm following Uncle Bob's clean architecture for my application.

However, I wish my application to be extensible via plugins. More specifically, I want the plugins to be able to add new entities and use cases.

How does one go about adding support for plugins in an application that follows the clean architecture?

[image]

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: This question is too broad. Try to narrow it down, for example, by describing the precise kind of application you are going to build, and give a detailed example of the kind of plugins it should support. And please don't try to invent something artificial just because I asked.

Answer (score 1):

Well according to Robert Martin this green stuff right here is a plugin.

[image]

So we're good right? No? Want to know more?

If by "support for plugins" you actually mean you want to be able to deploy your application and allow other people to add plugins to it without bothering you then you need a little more than just [Uncle Bobs folded over version of the Dependency Inversion Principle](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/148809/a-button-as-a-clean-architecture-plugin). You also need [a class loader that can load classes it's never heard of before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32205773/developing-application-with-plugin-support-in-java).

That is, if you're in a language that even has classes. A bit hard to nail this down without knowing the language.

My main point is still that while Mr. Martin is teaching you the UML of a plugin he's certainly not teaching you how to build a plugin management system into your application. It's a little more involved than understanding that DIP can fold.